# Getting the url that caused a java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, debugging

I'm getting this exception in my code:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:570)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:411)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:525)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:170)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1282)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1233)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:183)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.unBuffer(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:89)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:63)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.write(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:71)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.write(UTF8Writer.java:143)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flushBuffer(BufferingXmlWriter.java:1366)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.fastWriteRaw(BufferingXmlWriter.java:1412)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.writeAttribute(BufferingXmlWriter.java:901)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.doWriteAttr(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:508)
        ... 77 more
```

This is not very helpful to me.  But, if I could know the URL that's throwing this exception, this information would be extremely useful.  Is there some config option I can turn on to get an error message that shows me the URL?  This stack trace does not include any code that I've written, that's why it's so hard for me to debug.

Comment: Can we see the code block that you are executing that causes this? If you make the object you're working with accessible outside of the `try` block, you can test it in the `catch` block after I believe.

Comment: @Rogue: The code throwing this exception is a very big open source project that I have not modified but am using as a framework.  The code that throws the exception is very abstracted.  It's this line: `return oMethod.invoke(portObject, operationInput);`  `oMethod` is a `java.lang.reflect.Method`.  As you can see, if I could just get the URL itself it would be way easier than debugging the code.

Comment: In this case you would might better off using a packet sniffer such as Wireshark on Windows or tcpdump on Linux to trap the offending connection.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm curious as to why it has to come to this.  Is this a poorly designed exception?  Or is there a logical reason why this exception can't show me the URL?